# Splitting a string at every character

Tags: c#, string

let's say I have a string "hello world".  I would like to end up with " dehllloorw".  As I don't find any ready-made solution I thought: I can split the string into a character array, sort it and convert it back to a string.

In perl I can do `s//` but in .Net I'd have to do a `.Split()` but there's no overload with no parameters... if I do `.Split(null)` it seems to split by whitespace and `.Split('')` won't compile.

how do I do this (I hate to run a loop!)?

Comment: how do you.. umm what.. I can't even figure out what is being asked here.

Comment: how are you getting "dehlllor" from "hello world" ? Please explain !

Comment: I think its alphabetical order

Comment: @Marlon: and where did the 'w' go?

Comment: @ Marlon - if it is in alphabetical order then where is 'w' ?

Comment: I suppose I didn't see that! Maybe the OP made a typo :) They forgot the second 'o' also

Comment: yes, I didn't do a good job in my conversion and missed those letters.  thanks all the same, others figured out what I meant.

Comment: I lost 5 points on this question!  how come everyone?

Comment: @ekkis IDK, majority of the audience on SO are narcissistic pseudo intellects with chips on their shoulders. #DontTakeItPersonal

Comment: @Alex, haha.  it just cost me a lot of points!

Comment: @ekkis, perhaps @Alexander is right to some extent but IMHO you really have to do a better job of asking the question in the first place (especailly since you appear to be a native speaker)... BTW, I did not down-vote your question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.Sort("hello world".ToCharArray());`

Below is a quick demo console app

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var array = "hello world".ToCharArray();

            Array.Sort(array);

            Console.WriteLine(new String(array));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: that's actually half the answer since I'll still need to do a String.Concat()

Answer (score 3):

The characters in a string can be directly used, the string class exposed them as an enumeration - combine that with Linq / `OrderBy` and you have a one-liner to create the ordered output string:

```
string myString = "hello world";
string output = new string(myString.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray()); // dehllloorw
```

Comment: that's really cool.  I had tried that but couldn't figure out how to do the `.OrderBy()` - I tried to do it without a lambda expression

Answer (score 2):

You could always do this:

```
private static string SortStringCharacters(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return null;
    return new string(value.ToList().Sort().ToArray());
}
```

Comment: excellent.  I wonder how that compares (performance-wise) with Alexander Freiria's answer below...